# Minimal normal simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $N$ be a non-Abelian minimal normal subgroup of the finite group $G$, and let $\mathcal{K}$ be the set of minimal normal subgroups of $N$, then show that the elements of $\mathcal{K}$ are non-Abelian simple groups, which are **conjugate** in $G$.

I managed to show that all elements in $\mathcal{K}$ are non-Abelian simple groups, but I was stuck when it comes to showing that they are conjugate.

That they are conjugate means that the factors of the direct product would be **uniquely determined**, but how to deal with it?

$\ddot\smile$ Any help will be sincerely appreciated! Thanks!

**PS:** It’s 1.7.5 $(a)$ on page 38 of my textbook, [*The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction*](http://www.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/GruFus/Kurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%20of%20finite%20groups.pdf). It says that we can get the uniqueness from 1.6.3 $(b)$. But I find that it only helps me with 1.7.5 $(b)$. So what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the result in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691440/) that $N = E_1 \times \cdots \times E_k$, where the $E_i$ are nonabelian simple groups that are all conjugate in $G$.

So all that remains to prove is that the $E_i$ are the only minimal normal subgroup of $N$. To do that, suppose that $M$ is some minimal normal subgroup, and let $1 \ne h \in M$. Then we can write $h$ (uniquely) as $h_1h_2\ldots h_k$ with $h_i \in E_i$. Since $1 \ne h$, some $h_i \ne 1$. Since $E_i$ is nonabelian simple, $Z(E_i)=1$, so there exists $g \in E_i$ with $g \not\in C(h)$. The  $1 \ne [g,h] \in M \cap E_i$, and since $E_i$ is simple and $M \unlhd G$, we have $E_i \le M$ and then minimality of $M$ gives $M = E_i$.